# How to upgrade Rundeck from 2.6.9 to 3.2

Tags: rundeck

I have not seen any Rundeck documentation for an update from 2.6.x to 3.2. Is there a process to follow or site that covers the upgrade path? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am running CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 0):

The gap between Rundeck 2.6.X and 3.2.X is big. So, the main advice is to create a new instance with the latest version and import your projects (from your Rundeck 2.6.9), re-creating your resource nodes and keys. Take a look a [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup-and-recovery).

Anyway, you can follow [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading.html#rundeck-rpm-package) guide (for RPM-based instance) to upgrade your instance. Just make sure to test in a safe environment before.